# How to sort members alphabetically in /etc/group?

Tags: debian, sort, group

In my `/etc/group` file, I had the groups needed for various file shares, with their members listed. Some of these lists are quite long, and I'd like to find a way to sort the **members** of each group. Is there an easy way?

I'm using Bash on Debian 9.

So far, I found out how to select a group, and alphabetically sort their members:

`grep groupa /etc/group | cut -d":" -f4 | tr "," "\n" | sort`

This requires the name of the group to already be known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read each line from the groups file. Split the members by comma, sort them, join them together again. Print the line with the other untouched components.

```
while IFS=: read u x g members
do
    members=$(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$members" | sort | xargs | tr ' ' ',')
    printf "%s:%s:%d:%s\n" "$u" "$x" $g "$members"
done </etc/group
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Awk or Perl:

```
gawk -F: '
  $4 != "" {
    n = split($4,a,/,/);
    asort(a);
    for (i=1;i<n;i++) printf "%s,", a[i];
    print a[n]
  }
' /etc/group
```

or

```
perl -F: -lne '
  print join ",", sort split /,/, $F[3] if $F[3] =~ /\S/
' /etc/group
```

Both skip groups that have empty member lists; you can omit that test and / or re-write the other fields as well if you wish, ex.

```
$ perl -F: -lne 'print join ":", @F[0..2], join ",", sort split /,/, $F[3]' /etc/group > group.sorted
$
$ diff /etc/group group.sorted 
5c5
< adm:x:4:syslog,steeldriver
---
> adm:x:4:steeldriver,syslog
```